# Artificial Intelligence - How to decide the valuation for an auction bid?

Tags: swift, artificial-intelligence, decision-tree

I'm working on a project where there is an array of cards that are auctioned off; where the highest bidder will win the highest valued card on auction.

When the AI player is on turn, he needs to evaluate the array and determine a valuation of his bid.

Ignore anything to do with validation or rules; as I've already programmed and tested these.

My query is more specifically on how do I associate a value for a given array of values; and come up with a bidding value.

In the project, the cards range from 1...30; with 30 being the highest.

A single auction there could be 6 cards, shuffled and placed "on auction"

ie:

```
#1 - "Card name" - Value: 1
#2 - "Card name" - Value: 3
#3 - "Card name" - Value: 30
#4 - "Card name" - Value: 15
#5 - "Card name" - Value: 24
#6 - "Card name" - Value: 18
```

The question I have is, how does the computer review the values and come up with a determination of how much its worth to him to continue raising his bid, or even coming up with an opening bid?

There are some variables we do know.

- All card placed on auction
- Cash on hand
- How many auction rounds remain (For now, assume 6 auction rounds)

Given this, I've come up with a basic weighting solution.

IE:

```
var weight = 1.0

if roundsRemaining = 1 {
   weight += 0.35
}

if weight > 1.0 { 
   weight = 1.0 
}
```

Then I randomize between 0 and 1.0; the closer to 1.0 the more likely the bidding player will make a bid.

Whilst it gives me a probability of bidding, it doesn't tell me the *valuation* of his bid.

Ideally, I'd like the AI to review the cards on offer and place a bid based on what he thinks the highest card is worth (as this is what he is bidding for).

This is my query; given an array of cards with values and known parameters; how can the AI determine a valuation for making a bid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way is to use Statistics :)

You could average the cards in the auction, then compare that value to a known distribution of values (i.e. bell curve of all possible sets) to find the p-value for that auction. The higher the p-value the more valuable the set is, and the more the AI should being willing to pay for it.

This works because all values of any set will regress to the mean value.

If the auction set is not known, (that is to say that the players cannot see all cards in the auction) then the AI could 'guess' based on known p-values or memorize which cards have already been seen and remove them from the total distribution.

you can use this statistics library instead of having to write your own:
https://github.com/evgenyneu/SigmaSwiftStatistics

Comment: Sounds interesting, I'll give it a go. I'm not good with statistics; but its worth  shot